# How to connect Server Sents Events (SSE) to a PHP MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller, server-sent-events

So I currently have a working SSE system, which sends out notifications to clients. For the EventSource I specify a direct script on the server *notifs.php*.

Simplified this looks like following:
**client.js**

```
$(window).on('pageshow',function(){
   // Server Sent Events here
   if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
       var source = new EventSource("notifs.php");
       source.onmessage = function(event) { ... };
   }
});
```

And PHP side looks something like this:
**notifs.php**

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo 'data: {"Foo": "Bar}'.PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Now this works well, but I'd like to structure my whole project under the MVC design pattern, so instead of connecting the EventSource to "notifs.php" I'd like to have something like "/notification/notifs/", where notification is a Controller and notifs it's action.

Firefox tells me that it cannot create a connection to *localhost/notification/notifs/*. I would assume that this happens, because this is no real address on the server. While normal HTTP-requests go through a routing engine, this does not.

I wasn't able to find any information about this. Is it even possible to include the SSE endpoint in an object-oriented class? 
Or do they always have to be in their own files?